# UILabel accessibilityAttributedLabel not working for "Spoken Content" and the Accessibility Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, accessibility

I want to explicitly set the spoken language for one of my accessible UILabels. This is my example code:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is English but will be read in German", 
                                                 attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechLanguage : "de-DE"])

label.accessibilityAttributedLabel = attributedString
```

This works in the regular VoiceOver functionality. The voice actually reads the English text with a German accent, which is intended.

While this seems fine, the attributes that I set seem to be completely ignored in the Xcode Accessibility Inspector and the "Spoken Content" feature in iOS.

Can somebody help me to find out where this issue is coming from? Why is this not working with all the tools and is this documented somewhere?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but a comment: Accessibility Inspector on macOS is very limited. That's not documented afaik, but my experience. Best practice is to verify VoiceOver on a real device (which can be attached to Accessibility Inspector, too btw). Also note that if you try to set portions of an AttributedString to another language, `.languageIdentifier` might be required too.

Answer (score 0):

Override the property and return to true

```
override public var isAccessibilityElement: Bool { return true }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but this was not the issue because the element is already recognized as an accessible element